# How to change label's text programmatically for watchOS on Xcode

Tags: swift

I have a label setup on the watch interface of Xcode. How do I change text programmatically? I don't see a `.text` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `setText` method of label

```
yourlabel.setText("Hello")
```

Comment: And what to do in this case ? `if let message : String = countedLabel.setText() {
            do {....` this is not working. In iOS is `if let message : String = countedLabel.text {
            do {`